# Font Family & Font Awesome Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, font-family

**Question Background:**

I have a simple slider that renders within it both font-awesome icons and text.

**The Issue:**

I am mainly looking at Lucida Sans and Lucida Sans Unicode fonts. Depending on which of the fonts I select there seems to be top padding misalignment (or clear space) between the two. These differences mean I cannot come up with CSS that provides correct alignment for all font types.

**Lucida Sans - aligned icons with the text:**

[image]

**Lucida San Unicode - misaligned icons. Looks to be top-padding on the text:**

[image]

**Code:**

The following is the HTML for the items shown in the screenshots:

```
<div id="riskAmendments">
   <div id="taskAmendmentWidget1">
      <div class="riskCircleIconHolder"><span class="riskIcon"></span></div>
      <div class="riskDescription">Issue One</div>
      <a id="afc5d6c4-85d4-49e6-9231-565c4b867e62" href="#" class="riskResolveLink">
         <div class="riskSpannerIconHolder"><span class="riskIcon"></span></div>
         Resolve Issue
         <div class="riskChevronIconHolder"><span class="riskIcon"></span></div>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.riskIcon {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.riskDescription {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.riskResolveLink {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.riskCircleIconHolder {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 25px;
}

.riskSpannerIconHolder {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.riskChevronIconHolder {
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

**Is there a way to provide a CSS solution that will alignment all icons and text for their respective Font-family?**

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, this is a font limitation - they all have different ascender and descender dimensions and it's up to the designer to decide the vertical alignment - css is only concerned with the final character height (including spacing), but not with how the symbol itself is positioned within that height.

Answer (score 0):

there is two solutions for that :

```
.riskIcon {vertical-align:center}
```

try to use line height

```
.riskSpannerIconHolder {line-height:30px // for example}
.riskSpannerIconHolder .riskIcon {line-height:30px // for example}
```